# RxJS: Subject errors trickling down to subscribers

Tags: typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have a situation in which my `Subject` is returning an error, but the error method of an `Observable` subscribing to that `Subject` is being executed, even though the subscription of that `Observable` does not fail and return an error. Like this:

```
this.createPayment$ = this.wizard$.pipe(
  switchMap((wizard) => willReturnAnErrorObservable()),
  share()
);

this. handleSuccessSubscription = this.createPayment$.pipe(
  filter((someEvent: SomeEvent) => event.succeeded),
  switchMap((someEvent: SomeEvent) =>
      // this is never called because the filter above does not pass
      doesNotFailObservable()
  )
).subscribe((confirmedPayment: PaymentDeviceEvent) => {
  // not important
},
  (error) => {
  // this error block is still being called, even though the this.
  // handleSuccessSubscription switchMap is not executed, because the 
  // this.handleSuccessSubscription$ above returns an error
});
```

In this code, the `createPaymentSuccessfulSubscription`'s error method is being executed, even though the `switchMap` returns ok, which is because the 'outer' `Subject` is throwing an error.

Is there any way to prevent subscribers also receiving the errors? It's not critical, because I can filter on the `error` returned to determine if it needs to be handled here; but it's a bit smelly and I would like this error block not to be executed at all.

Comment: can you provide stackbiz , really not getting much from this

Answer (score 0):

You should catch errors and handle them before it is passed to the final consumer

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, switchMap, share } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.createPayment$ = this.wizard$.pipe(
  switchMap((wizard) => willReturnAnErrorObservable()),
  catchError((error) => of(console.log('log error', error))),
  share(),
);
```